# How to run A-Frame code from another file to prevent clutter?

Tags: aframe

Using A-Frame creates a lot of clutter. Is their a way to access the code from another file? If not then what do you recommend for preventing cluster? My code is public @ https://repl.it/@ColbzDaBoss1/A-Frame-Test

Thanks :)
Colby Bianco

Answer (score 0):

Use components: https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html

```
<script src="my-component.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity my-component></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

component file:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('my-component', {
  init: function () {
  }
});
```

Comment: So this worked I think... But I can't run things like `<a-plane position="0 0 -2" rotation="-90 0 0" width="5" height="5" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>` cause it's html. Is there a JavaScript equivalent for this code? Thanks!!!